# Multiple Windows Navigating the same datacollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a (non MVVM) WPF C# application that evaluates oil and gas wells that I want to refactor to MVVM.  One window shows the tabular information and another window shows the graphical rendition of the same data.  Both have navigation buttons to move from well to well.

How can I have record selection changes in one window automatically change the selected record and datagrid focus in the other window using MVVM without having the ViewModels know the properties of the windows.  Currently Window One shares the listview selected item property of the other Window.

Answer (score 0):

You want Mode=TwoWay on your binding paths, with an INotifyPropertyChanged event on your objects. This should update every element bound to the data collection.

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx for more information on the Binding Modes as well as implementing INotifyPropertyChanged events.